# overpass-api ways query include coordinates

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm trying to query Hotels in a specific area. Unfortunately I need to query nodes and ways, because some Hotels are only stored as way and some as nodes.

```
http://overpass.osm.rambler.ru/cgi/interpreter?data=%28way[tourism~hotel]%28around:5000,50.10707,8.76040%29%29;out;
```

The result of a way-query doesn't contain any coordinates, only lots of node-refs:

```
<nd ref="1438833423"/>
```

Is there a way also to include the coordinates of the nodes in the output or do have to start lots of additional queries for each node?

Tom

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there are several ways to also get geometries for non-node features via the Overpass API. The easiest is probably to use the `center` output mode (replace `out;` with `out center;`): http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/4O4. Other options would be to fetch the node references in a recursion step: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/4O5 or using the [full geometry output mode](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Print_.28out.29).

PS: Don't forget that a hotel can also be mapped as a (multipolygon) relation in OSM, not just as a node or way.

Comment: "out center", so simple, thx alot :) Maybe this should be added to the wiki http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide.

Comment: Yes, implementing the recently added geometry output modes for the JSON format is a todo, see this [github ticket](https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/93) for more info.

Comment: out:json should work by now. This feature was pushed to production only recently. I agree that the language guide needs some updating wrt to new output modes.

Answer (score 4):

Necromancing.

And to actually answer the question:

```
[out:json];
way(29858799);
out ids geom;
```

Which will give you the geometries for each point in the selected way.

```
{
  "version": 0.6,
  "generator": "Overpass API",
  "osm3s": {
    "timestamp_osm_base": "2017-10-06T13:59:02Z",
    "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL."
  },
  "elements": [

{
  "type": "way",
  "id": 29858799,
  "bounds": {
    "minlat": 47.3604067,
    "minlon": 8.5342631,
    "maxlat": 47.3612503,
    "maxlon": 8.5352457
  },
  "geometry": [
    { "lat": 47.3612503, "lon": 8.5351944 },
    { "lat": 47.3612252, "lon": 8.5342631 },
    { "lat": 47.3610145, "lon": 8.5342755 },
    { "lat": 47.3610212, "lon": 8.5345227 },
    { "lat": 47.3606405, "lon": 8.5345451 },
    { "lat": 47.3606350, "lon": 8.5343411 },
    { "lat": 47.3604067, "lon": 8.5343545 },
    { "lat": 47.3604120, "lon": 8.5345623 },
    { "lat": 47.3604308, "lon": 8.5352457 },
    { "lat": 47.3606508, "lon": 8.5352328 },
    { "lat": 47.3606413, "lon": 8.5348784 },
    { "lat": 47.3610383, "lon": 8.5348551 },
    { "lat": 47.3610477, "lon": 8.5352063 },
    { "lat": 47.3612503, "lon": 8.5351944 }
  ]
}

  ]
}
```

https://overpass-turbo.eu/

All the options for out are listed here:
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Print_.28out.29